# Get access to another window textEntry (Python)

Tags: python, gtk, pycharm, glade

I'm using PyCharm and Glade user interface designer.
My project contains two windows: **Main** and **Secondary**. **Secondary** window starts from **Main**. After some manipulation in **Secondary** window I should close it. But before I'm saving some data in a `list`. And when **Secondary** window is closed I want to fill some `textEntry` on **Main** window with my data from `list`.

What is the best way to handle it?
I'm newbie in Python. Probably better to catch the signal when secondary window is closed? Or fill `textEntry`of **Main** window right in the code of another window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options, pass the list or a function that modifies the list to the secondary window.

For example this is how the function could be passed:

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
      s = Secondary(self.modify_list)
      mylist = []

      .
      .

      s.run()

      .
      .

   def modify_list(self, new_values):
       mylist = new_values

class Secondary():
   def __init__(self, modify_list):
       self.modify_list = modify_list

   .
   .

   def apply(self):
       new_text = self.entry.get_buffer()
       self.modify_list(new_text)
```

Let me know if that worked for you!